# Account is not revealed even after reveal operation

Tags: reveal

I created a new account and funded it.

Then I had to perform a reveal operation to get an opportunity to make transfers. It succeeded and account became revealed (explorer api returned `is_revealed` = true)
But after sending funds I still receive `is_revealed` = false and I need to do another reveal operation.
Why? What's wrong?

Account - https://tzstats.com/tz1dG8jzk8jgSpA3z6CwTz7jCJ2yFMHLCuqN

API call - https://api.tzstats.com/explorer/account/tz1dG8jzk8jgSpA3z6CwTz7jCJ2yFMHLCuqN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you withdraw the whole deposit from your account (so that its balance is zero), the account is removed from the blockchain context, so all information about previous reveals is lost and you have to reveal your public key again.

Here is an example of an account that reveals his key, then withdraws everything, then reveals the key again, then withdraws everything, etc.: https://tzkt.io/tz1Ycddr9fYZMiN6gKaTYTUk6Bgdvq2PHHZb/operations

To avoid that you can leave any small amount on the account to prevent it from emptying (removing from the context).

---

Note, baker accounts and smart contracts are never removed, even if their balance is zero.